i cant install java to run my mcc server

Uninstalled Java because it was a headless version, which was causing errors.
Attempted to reinstall Java but encountered a new issue.
Tried fixing the issue multiple times but couldn't resolve it.
Currently feeling stuck and unsure about the root cause.

Troubleshooting steps taken:

Ran apt-get update
Restarted the PC.
Referenced logs or code at this https://codeshare.io/P83wwo

Welcome to Ubuntu 23.10 (GNU/Linux 6.5.0-44-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/pro

9 updates can be applied immediately.
To see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable

Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

New release '24.04.1 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

Last login: Wed Dec  4 21:12:08 2024 from 192.168.1.139
jacob@thedor:~$ java
Command 'java' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install default-jre              # version 2:1.17-74, or
sudo apt install openjdk-17-jre-headless  # version 17.0.11+9-1~23.10.1
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless  # version 11.0.23+9-1ubuntu1~23.10.1
sudo apt install openjdk-21-jre-headless  # version 21.0.3+9-1ubuntu1~23.10.1
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless   # version 8u412-ga-1~23.10.1
sudo apt install openjdk-19-jre-headless  # version 19.0.2+7-4
sudo apt install openjdk-20-jre-headless  # version 20.0.2+9-1
sudo apt install openjdk-22-jre-headless  # version 22~16ea-1
jacob@thedor:~$ sudo apt install default-jre
[sudo] password for jacob:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java default-jre-headless fonts-dejavu-extra java-common
  libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni openjdk-17-jre
  openjdk-17-jre-headless
Suggested packages:
  fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-ipafont-mincho fonts-wqy-microhei
  | fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-indic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java default-jre default-jre-headless fonts-dejavu-extra
  java-common libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni openjdk-17-jre
  openjdk-17-jre-headless
0 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
Need to get 48.2 MB/50.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 200 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/main amd64 ca-certificates-java all 20230710
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security/main amd64 openjdk-17-jre-headless amd64 17.0.11+9-1~23.10.1
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/main amd64 java-common all 0.74
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
Err:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/main amd64 default-jre-headless amd64 2:1.17-74
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
Err:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/main amd64 default-jre amd64 2:1.17-74
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
Err:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/main amd64 libatk-wrapper-java all 0.40.0-3
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
Err:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/main amd64 libatk-wrapper-java-jni amd64 0.40.0-3
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
Ign:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security/main amd64 openjdk-17-jre amd64 17.0.11+9-1~23.10.1
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security/main amd64 openjdk-17-jre-headless amd64 17.0.11+9-1~23.10.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::103 80]
Err:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security/main amd64 openjdk-17-jre amd64 17.0.11+9-1~23.10.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::103 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/ca-certificates-java/ca-certificates-java_20230710_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/j/java-common/java-common_0.74_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-17/openjdk-17-jre-headless_17.0.11%2b9-1%7e23.10.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::103 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/j/java-common/default-jre-headless_1.17-74_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-17/openjdk-17-jre_17.0.11%2b9-1%7e23.10.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::103 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/j/java-common/default-jre_1.17-74_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/j/java-atk-wrapper/libatk-wrapper-java_0.40.0-3_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/j/java-atk-wrapper/libatk-wrapper-java-jni_0.40.0-3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
jacob@thedor:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic InRelease
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security InRelease
Ign:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates InRelease
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::103 80]
Ign:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-backports InRelease
Get:6 https://ngrok-agent.s3.amazonaws.com buster InRelease [20.3 kB]
Err:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
Err:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
Err:6 https://ngrok-agent.s3.amazonaws.com buster InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0E61D3BBAAEE37FE
Err:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
Ign:10 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu mantic InRelease
Ign:11 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu mantic InRelease
Err:12 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu mantic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::81 443]
Err:13 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu mantic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::81 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: https://ngrok-agent.s3.amazonaws.com buster InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0E61D3BBAAEE37FE
E: The repository 'https://ngrok-agent.s3.amazonaws.com buster InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu mantic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu mantic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
jacob@thedor:~$ sudo apt install default-jre
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java default-jre-headless fonts-dejavu-extra java-common
  libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni openjdk-17-jre
  openjdk-17-jre-headless
Suggested packages:
  fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-ipafont-mincho fonts-wqy-microhei
  | fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-indic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java default-jre default-jre-headless fonts-dejavu-extra
  java-common libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni openjdk-17-jre
  openjdk-17-jre-headless
0 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
Need to get 48.2 MB/50.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 200 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/main amd64 ca-certificates-java all 20230710
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security/main amd64 openjdk-17-jre-headless amd64 17.0.11+9-1~23.10.1
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/main amd64 java-common all 0.74
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
Err:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/main amd64 default-jre-headless amd64 2:1.17-74
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
Err:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/main amd64 default-jre amd64 2:1.17-74
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
Err:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/main amd64 libatk-wrapper-java all 0.40.0-3
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
Err:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/main amd64 libatk-wrapper-java-jni amd64 0.40.0-3
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
Ign:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security/main amd64 openjdk-17-jre amd64 17.0.11+9-1~23.10.1
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security/main amd64 openjdk-17-jre-headless amd64 17.0.11+9-1~23.10.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::103 80]
Err:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security/main amd64 openjdk-17-jre amd64 17.0.11+9-1~23.10.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::103 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/ca-certificates-java/ca-certificates-java_20230710_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/j/java-common/java-common_0.74_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-17/openjdk-17-jre-headless_17.0.11%2b9-1%7e23.10.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::103 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/j/java-common/default-jre-headless_1.17-74_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-17/openjdk-17-jre_17.0.11%2b9-1%7e23.10.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::103 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/j/java-common/default-jre_1.17-74_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/j/java-atk-wrapper/libatk-wrapper-java_0.40.0-3_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/j/java-atk-wrapper/libatk-wrapper-java-jni_0.40.0-3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
jacob@thedor:~$ sudo apt list --udates
E: Command line option --udates is not understood in combination with the other options
jacob@thedor:~$ ^C
jacob@thedor:~$ ^C
jacob@thedor:~$ sudo apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
grub-common/mantic-updates 2.12~rc1-10ubuntu4.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.12~rc1-10ubuntu4]
grub-efi-amd64-bin/mantic-updates 2.12~rc1-10ubuntu4.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.12~rc1-10ubuntu4]
grub-efi-amd64-signed/mantic-updates 1.197.2+2.12~rc1-10ubuntu4.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.197+2.12~rc1-10ubuntu4]
grub-efi-amd64/mantic-updates 2.12~rc1-10ubuntu4.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.12~rc1-10ubuntu4]
grub2-common/mantic-updates 2.12~rc1-10ubuntu4.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.12~rc1-10ubuntu4]
tzdata-icu/mantic-updates 2024a-0ubuntu0.23.10.1 all [upgradable from: 2024a-0ubuntu0.23.10]
tzdata/mantic-updates 2024a-0ubuntu0.23.10.1 all [upgradable from: 2024a-0ubuntu0.23.10]
ubuntu-advantage-tools/mantic-updates 32.3.1~23.10 all [upgradable from: 32.3~23.10]
ubuntu-pro-client-l10n/mantic-updates 32.3.1~23.10 amd64 [upgradable from: 32.3~23.10]
ubuntu-pro-client/mantic-updates 32.3.1~23.10 amd64 [upgradable from: 32.3~23.10]
xserver-common/mantic-updates 2:21.1.7-3ubuntu2.10 all [upgradable from: 2:21.1.7-3ubuntu2.9]
xserver-xephyr/mantic-updates 2:21.1.7-3ubuntu2.10 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:21.1.7-3ubuntu2.9]
xserver-xorg-core/mantic-updates 2:21.1.7-3ubuntu2.10 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:21.1.7-3ubuntu2.9]
xserver-xorg-legacy/mantic-updates 2:21.1.7-3ubuntu2.10 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:21.1.7-3ubuntu2.9]
jacob@thedor:~$ apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
grub-common/mantic-updates 2.12~rc1-10ubuntu4.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.12~rc1-10ubuntu4]
grub-efi-amd64-bin/mantic-updates 2.12~rc1-10ubuntu4.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.12~rc1-10ubuntu4]
grub-efi-amd64-signed/mantic-updates 1.197.2+2.12~rc1-10ubuntu4.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.197+2.12~rc1-10ubuntu4]
grub-efi-amd64/mantic-updates 2.12~rc1-10ubuntu4.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.12~rc1-10ubuntu4]
grub2-common/mantic-updates 2.12~rc1-10ubuntu4.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.12~rc1-10ubuntu4]
tzdata-icu/mantic-updates 2024a-0ubuntu0.23.10.1 all [upgradable from: 2024a-0ubuntu0.23.10]
tzdata/mantic-updates 2024a-0ubuntu0.23.10.1 all [upgradable from: 2024a-0ubuntu0.23.10]
ubuntu-advantage-tools/mantic-updates 32.3.1~23.10 all [upgradable from: 32.3~23.10]
ubuntu-pro-client-l10n/mantic-updates 32.3.1~23.10 amd64 [upgradable from: 32.3~23.10]
ubuntu-pro-client/mantic-updates 32.3.1~23.10 amd64 [upgradable from: 32.3~23.10]
xserver-common/mantic-updates 2:21.1.7-3ubuntu2.10 all [upgradable from: 2:21.1.7-3ubuntu2.9]
xserver-xephyr/mantic-updates 2:21.1.7-3ubuntu2.10 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:21.1.7-3ubuntu2.9]
xserver-xorg-core/mantic-updates 2:21.1.7-3ubuntu2.10 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:21.1.7-3ubuntu2.9]
xserver-xorg-legacy/mantic-updates 2:21.1.7-3ubuntu2.10 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:21.1.7-3ubuntu2.9]
jacob@thedor:~$ apt-get update
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
jacob@thedor:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic InRelease
Get:2 https://ngrok-agent.s3.amazonaws.com buster InRelease [20.3 kB]
Ign:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates InRelease
Ign:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-backports InRelease
Ign:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security InRelease
Err:2 https://ngrok-agent.s3.amazonaws.com buster InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0E61D3BBAAEE37FE
Err:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::101 80]
Err:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::101 80]
Err:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::103 80]
Err:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::101 80]
Ign:10 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu mantic InRelease
Ign:11 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu mantic InRelease
Err:12 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu mantic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::81 443]
Err:13 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu mantic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::81 443]
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://ngrok-agent.s3.amazonaws.com buster InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0E61D3BBAAEE37FE
E: The repository 'https://ngrok-agent.s3.amazonaws.com buster InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu mantic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu mantic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
jacob@thedor:~$ java
Command 'java' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install default-jre              # version 2:1.17-74, or
sudo apt install openjdk-17-jre-headless  # version 17.0.11+9-1~23.10.1
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless  # version 11.0.23+9-1ubuntu1~23.10.1
sudo apt install openjdk-21-jre-headless  # version 21.0.3+9-1ubuntu1~23.10.1
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless   # version 8u412-ga-1~23.10.1
sudo apt install openjdk-19-jre-headless  # version 19.0.2+7-4
sudo apt install openjdk-20-jre-headless  # version 20.0.2+9-1
sudo apt install openjdk-22-jre-headless  # version 22~16ea-1
jacob@thedor:~$ ^C
jacob@thedor:~$ ^C
jacob@thedor:~$ sudo apt install default-jre
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java default-jre-headless fonts-dejavu-extra java-common
  libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni openjdk-17-jre
  openjdk-17-jre-headless
Suggested packages:
  fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-ipafont-mincho fonts-wqy-microhei
  | fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-indic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java default-jre default-jre-headless fonts-dejavu-extra
  java-common libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni openjdk-17-jre
  openjdk-17-jre-headless
0 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
Need to get 48.2 MB/50.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 200 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/main amd64 ca-certificates-java all 20230710
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/main amd64 java-common all 0.74
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/main amd64 default-jre-headless amd64 2:1.17-74
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
Err:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/main amd64 default-jre amd64 2:1.17-74
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
Err:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/main amd64 libatk-wrapper-java all 0.40.0-3
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
Err:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/main amd64 libatk-wrapper-java-jni amd64 0.40.0-3
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
Ign:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security/main amd64 openjdk-17-jre-headless amd64 17.0.11+9-1~23.10.1
Err:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security/main amd64 openjdk-17-jre-headless amd64 17.0.11+9-1~23.10.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::102 80]
Ign:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security/main amd64 openjdk-17-jre amd64 17.0.11+9-1~23.10.1
Err:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security/main amd64 openjdk-17-jre amd64 17.0.11+9-1~23.10.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::102 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/ca-certificates-java/ca-certificates-java_20230710_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/j/java-common/java-common_0.74_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-17/openjdk-17-jre-headless_17.0.11%2b9-1%7e23.10.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::102 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/j/java-common/default-jre-headless_1.17-74_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-17/openjdk-17-jre_17.0.11%2b9-1%7e23.10.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::102 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/j/java-common/default-jre_1.17-74_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/j/java-atk-wrapper/libatk-wrapper-java_0.40.0-3_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/j/java-atk-wrapper/libatk-wrapper-java-jni_0.40.0-3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
jacob@thedor:~$ java
Command 'java' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install default-jre              # version 2:1.17-74, or
sudo apt install openjdk-17-jre-headless  # version 17.0.11+9-1~23.10.1
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless  # version 11.0.23+9-1ubuntu1~23.10.1
sudo apt install openjdk-21-jre-headless  # version 21.0.3+9-1ubuntu1~23.10.1
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless   # version 8u412-ga-1~23.10.1
sudo apt install openjdk-19-jre-headless  # version 19.0.2+7-4
sudo apt install openjdk-20-jre-headless  # version 20.0.2+9-1
sudo apt install openjdk-22-jre-headless  # version 22~16ea-1
jacob@thedor:~$ ^C
jacob@thedor:~$ ^C
jacob@thedor:~$ ^C
jacob@thedor:~$ sudo apt install openjdk-17-jre-headless
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java java-common
Suggested packages:
  default-jre fonts-dejavu-extra fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-ipafont-mincho
  fonts-wqy-microhei | fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-indic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java java-common openjdk-17-jre-headless
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
Need to get 47.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 193 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/main amd64 ca-certificates-java all 20230710
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::103 80]
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security/main amd64 openjdk-17-jre-headless amd64 17.0.11+9-1~23.10.1
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/main amd64 java-common all 0.74
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::103 80]
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security/main amd64 openjdk-17-jre-headless amd64 17.0.11+9-1~23.10.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::103 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/ca-certificates-java/ca-certificates-java_20230710_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::103 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/j/java-common/java-common_0.74_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::103 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-17/openjdk-17-jre-headless_17.0.11%2b9-1%7e23.10.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::103 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

